# Cannot Push in Eclipse GIT?

Tags: git, eclipse-cdt, egit

It shows 9 committed changes that haven't been pushed (as there is an up arrow with '9' next to it).

However, when I click on "push to upstream", it indicates the branch is "up to date".

Then, I am confused why the up arrow appears...

Comment: A screen shot of the history and the contents of the `.git/config` file in your repository would help figuring out what the problem might be.

Comment: After my coworkers and I ran into many issues/confusions with eGIT, we decided to stick with command line/smartgit.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the

> Branch Configuration

in the GIT Repositories View and the

> Push to Upstream configuration

in the Team -> Remote ->

Save and Push